# WPF Datagrid copies and pastes on click, why?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a wpf C#-project with a standard wpf datagrid that is populated from a data table. It is rebound to the table every time the source changes (since I sometime use the datagrid to display data from different source). I handle the SelectedCellsChanged event to highlight the selected column, and the CellEditEnding event to update the source table with any cell changes made by user.

Here´s the strange thing: when I double click a cell and then click another cell, the value from the double-clicked cell is pasted to the clicked cell. I don’t handle Cell double click at all, this behavior seems to be intrinsic to the datagrid, but I cannot google my way to any info.

I would like to either get rid of this behavior, or be able to catch it (my application records and repeats any action made by the user and the one-click copy paste is actually quite neat, if I could just catch and save the action).

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint in your code during the SelectedCellsChanged and CellEditEnding.  Is it POSSIBLE?? you are trying to write something at the same time the datagrid is in the middle of getting updated?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was my code that caused the problem. Problem is, the CellEditEnding event is raised when cell loses focus and I managed to update the cell being clicked with the edited value of the previous cell (the one that lost focus.)

I struggled to find a solution, since there is no cell-leave event. Finally solved it, not very pretty, like this:

```
string rrow = MyGrid.Items.IndexOf(MyGrid.CurrentItem);
if (!(e.Column.Header.ToString() == MyDataTable.Columns[selectedColumn].ColumnName && e.Row.GetIndex() == rrow))
 return;
```